# unable to parse the input : keystore

Tags: java, android, console, keystore, public-key-encryption

I am trying to encrypt the Keystore file to upload the certificate into Google play Console, I am using pepk.jar in the terminal in mac

Any idea why I am having this error

java -jar pepk.jar —keystore Mykeystore.keystore —alias  MyAlias --encryptionkey=eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b656cd48b9de6a —output=MyOutputFile
Error: Unable to parse the input: [—keystore, Mykeystore.keystore, —alias, MyAlias, --encryptionkey=eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b656cd48b9de6a, —output=MyOutputFile]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid argument: —keystore
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.Utils.processArgs(Utils.java:32)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.main(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:79)

Answer (score 4):

I found it, two things:
1- there where some typo in my command, here is the right one:
java -jar pepk.jar --keystore Mykeystore.keystore --alias MyAlias --encryptionkey=eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b656cd48b9de6a -- output=MyOutputFile
2- the output file should be .zip file
And now all works fine.

Comment: Thank you Lydia, 4 years later and this is still relevant: Google publishes the command in tha Play Console with errors. In my case, encryptionkey was auto-translated to spanish and all fields had an "=" that the tool is unable to parse. Your post and response guided me into the solution.